# dynamic url(separated by slash) paramters get to array? (eg : /category,cat1,cat2/types,type1,type2)

Tags: php, laravel

**have a good day guys!, im currently working on eCommerce like product filter,controller get request from front-end main category and parameters separated by slash('/'). URL parameters send like this:**

```
example.com/skin-care/categories,facial-cleansers-toners/collection,classic/skin-types,normal,soft
```

these URL open when user select attributes from filter. so after `example.com/skin-care/` is totally dynamic.

`/skin-care`  - main category
after first slash separate, all parameters dynamic attributes.
eg : `/{attribute},value1,value1,..`

so above examples have 1 main category slug and, 3 attributes (categories,collection,skin-types) and values of that attributes

i just need get these attributes to Associative array. just like this:

```
$attributes = ['categories' => ['facial-cleansers-toners'],
        'collection' => ['classic'],
        'skin-types' => ['normal','soft']
        ];
```

thank you

Comment: why you do not manage these attributes by POST?

Comment: can't do form 'POST' requests, because  its not SEO friendly.  and if user refreshed page, it also ask to resubmit data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your url is:

```
$static_url = "http://example.com/skin-care/categories,facial-cleansers-toners/collection,classic/skin-types,normal,soft";
```

first of all, we have to parse your URL to get our needed parameters :

```
$url_components = parse_url($static_url);
```

this variable outputs 3 items `scheme`, `host` and `path`. we need just **`path`** from here, so:

```
$url_path = $url_components['path'];
```

in the next level, we need to remove the first `/` character from the string and explode the string by `/` character:

```
$url_path_params = ltrim($url_path, $url_path[0]);
$url_attributes = explode('/', $url_path_params);
```

in this section we have the main category that maybe you need:

```
$main_category = $url_attributes[0]; // skin-care
```

we don't need the first item (`$main_category = 'skin-care'`) here so:

```
array_shift($url_attributes);
```

in the last step we got the `$url_attributes` that we need to fill in the attributes array with foreach loop and explode the string by `,` just like this:

```
$attributes = [];
foreach ($url_attributes as $attribute_key => $attribute_value) {
    $each_attribute = explode(',', $attribute_value);
    $cat = array_shift($each_attribute);

    $attributes[$cat] = $each_attribute;
}
```

if you get output from `$attributes` you got your needed data. in var_dump output this returns:

[image: output]

you can access to skin_types by: `$attributes["skin-types"]`.

[**Check the whole source in PHP Sandbox**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/807f68fcb79d05a33eae53db31209e25fa851f14)

Comment: thank you very much!... very informative your answer

Comment: you're welcome. I'm glad that helped you.